# How to use Unix sort command on a file that has a header line?

Tags: bash, unix

How can I omit the header row in my csv file with sort?

So far I have this:

```
sort -o  ./trans.csv -k 1,1n ./trans.csv
```

It works well apart from the header row gets sorted also.

Comment: Do you want the output to not include a header at all, or the header to be there but at the top?

Answer (score 6):

To keep the header in your output, and sort all non-header lines:

```
# create a temporary file to store output to
infile="trans.csv"
tempfile=$(mktemp "${infile}.XXXXXX")

if {
  IFS= read -r header            # read header from input to variable
  printf '%s\n' "$header"        # write header from variable to output
  sort -k 1,1n                   # pass all other input to output through sort
} <"$infile" >"$tempfile"; then  # if sort reports success (exit status 0)
  mv -- "$tempfile" "$infile"    # ...then atomically rename over input
else                             # if sort fails...
  echo "ERROR: Output file and input file have different line counts" >&2
  rm -f "$tempfile"              # then delete the temporary file.
  false                          # and ensure that $? reflects a failure
fi
```

Note that the `if` block only checks the exit status of `sort`, on the theory that we care more about whether the data made it through than the header. Consider using `&&`s instead of newlines to attach the items in the block if this isn't preferred.

Comment: This is nice.  Note that it doesn't necessarily check the status of `sort`, since it is possible that `sort` will not even be run.  (Permission error when redirecting, for example.)  However, it does the right thing in that case.  But you might want to add an 'exit 1' in the else clause (or just `false`) to indicate failure to the caller.

Comment: Good point. Since I'm not sure this intended for use as a standalone script, I'm hesitant to use `exit`; `false` may be just the thing, inasmuch as it'll properly set our last command's exit status (and thus the exit status of the enclosing function or script) regardless of context.

Answer (score 2):

```
( sed -u 1q; sort -k 1,1n ) < trans.csv > trans-sorted.csv
```

(so suggested in the [GNU Coreutils Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Header-lines.html))

The `-u` option is important to not lose data (see comments).

or:

```
( read header; echo $header; sort -k 1,1n ) < trans.csv > trans-sorted.csv
```

To end up with the same filename: Add `&& mv trans-sorted.csv trans.csv`:

```
( read header; echo $header; sort -k 1,1n ) < trans.csv > trans-sorted.csv && mv trans-sorted.csv trans.csv
```

Comment: This is risky.  `read` is guaranteed to read only one line, but `sed` and `head` offer no such guarantee and data might be lost doing this.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Could you explain why you find `sed` and `head` might read more than one line?

Comment: Because they do!  For example, in `printf 'foo\nbar\n' | { sed 1q; while read l; do echo "l=$l"; done; }` on my box, the while loop reads no data.  But it does in `printf 'foo\nbar\n' | { read line; echo "$line"; while read l; do echo "l=$l"; done; }`

Comment: `sed` and `head` both read data in large chunks before they process it, so it is nearly certain they will read more than one line.  The only way to avoid reading more than one line is to read data one byte at a time, which makes the IO unbearably slow.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I see, good points, appeciate the input. `sed` offers the `-u` flag, which seams to address this issue. In your example it seamed to solve the issue. I updateed my answer to include a version using `read`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tail` to skip the first line:

```
tail -n +2 ./trans.csv | sort -o ./trans.csv -k 1,1n
```

`-n +2` means "start output from the second line of input".

Comment: Should probably suggest `set -o pipefail` first -- otherwise, if `tail` fails, the command as a whole will still return success. (Though even with the exit status reflecting failure, you're potentially in a situation of having overwritten the output file).

Comment: In this case, the output file will miss the header line, unlike @CharlesDuffy's solution.

Comment: @codeforester, ...though to be fair, the OP isn't clear on whether they want to omit the header *from being sorted*, or omit it *from the output*. It may well turn out that this is what they want (though I remain hesitant to use or endorse `sort -o` without explicit documentation on its behavior -- whether it opens the file at the beginning of output, renames to it at the end, &c -- and without a means to ensure that we don't overwrite an output file in entirety should the read process fail partway through).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that :

```
(read line;echo $line;(while read line;do echo $line;done) | sort -k 1,1n)<infile
```

Comment: The `while read line; do echo $line` loop is a fair bit of performance overhead, and I'm unclear as to what benefit you see in it (as opposed to letting `sort` reading the remaining content direct from stdin, as it does in my answer). It even has correctness impact: If you have a line that has a `*` in it surrounded by spaces, `echo $line` will replace that with a list of files in the current directory. Similarly, tabs will be replaced with spaces, and runs of spaces will be collapsed to only one space.

Comment: ...if terseness is more important than correctness, I'd argue that the now-deleted answer by William Purcell (similar to this in general but without the aforementioned bugs) strikes a better balance.